# How to fill circle border based on progress in REACTJS

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-state-management

How to complete the border of circle based on selected option.
Here is four options.
1.Head
2.Body
3.Script
4.End Note

And I have a circle on side. What I am trying to do is, Head is by default active so circle border should be red color till 25% of its total area, then after selection of body it should be 50%. So on and at the end it should 100%.

Here is my code which I tried on click its changing text color till 4 clicks but I want above kind of thing.Being beginner in ReactJS I am unable to get this logic.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";


export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       title: "Click here",
       color:"red",
       active:false,
      clicks: 0,
    }
 }
 getInitialState() {
  return {
    count: 0
  };
}

 changeTitle = () => {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    clicks: prevState.clicks + 1,
    title: "New title",color:"green",active:true,
 }));

 };

 render() {

     return (
     <div>
       <div>count:{this.state.clicks}</div>
       <h1 onClick={this.changeTitle.bind(this)} >Hello World </h1>
       <h1 style={this.state.clicks===1 ? {color:"red"}: 
                 (this.state.clicks===2)?{color:"yellow"}:
                 (this.state.clicks===2)?{color:"black"}:
                 {color:"green"}}>This is Magic: {this.state.title}</h1>;
     </div>
     )  
 }
}
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have some kind of circle (not sure where it is.. maybe your second `h1` element is circle-shaped?), and you want its border to be correspondingly filled when you select different options (home, body, etc..)?

Comment: please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50207948/convert-the-circle-border-onto-clickable-function @Kox I want something like this

Comment: I believe @Ron has already answered your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50208291/7956790

Comment: ya some moment ago but its in jquery not in js

Answer (score 0):

Shoutout to @Ron for providing an answer in jquery (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50208291/7956790).
Use the css provided by @Ron.
Ok, here's the render function in React:

```
// your previous code
render() {
 return (
  <div id="circle-container">
     <div className="quarter top-left">
       <div className="quarter-fill top-left-fill" onClick={this.handleTopLeftClick}></div>
     </div>
     <div className="quarter top-right">
        <div className="quarter-fill top-right-fill" onClick={this.handleTopRightClick}></div>
     </div>
     <div className="quarter bottom-left">
        <div className="quarter-fill bottom-left-fill" onClick={this.handleBottomLeftClick}></div>
     </div>
     <div className="quarter bottom-right">
        <div className="quarter-fill bottom-right-fill" onClick={this.handleBottomRightClick}></div>
     </div>
  </div>
 );
}
```

Hook your onClick listeners to your arcs, e.g. `onClick={this.handleTopRightClick}` and bind them in the constructor function:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
   this.handleTopLeftClick.bind(this);
   this.handleTopRightClick.bind(this);
   this.handleBottomLeftClick.bind(this);
   this.handleBottomRightClick.bind(this);
}
```

And now define your handler functions in your class:

```
handleTopLeftClick() { }
handleTopRightClick() { }
handleBottomLeftClick() { }
handleBottomLeftClick() { }
```